# How would I use AWS SDK for iOS to create a CloudWatch event rule using a cron job in Xcode using Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, events, cron, aws-sdk-ios

How would I use AWS SDK for iOS to create a CloudWatch event rule using a cron job in Xcode using Swift? So far I have found this [AWSCloudWatch Reference](https://aws-amplify.github.io/aws-sdk-ios/docs/reference/AWSCloudWatch/Classes/AWSCloudWatchSetAlarmStateInput.html), but I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the official documentation provided by AWS for AWS SDK for iOS for AWS CloudWatch service: [AWS SDK for iOS - AWSCloudWatch Reference](https://aws-amplify.github.io/aws-sdk-ios/docs/reference/AWSCloudWatch/index.html)

**It doesn't have the capability to create AWS CloudWatch events yet.**

You can call some other SDK's code or use AWS API Gateway to call AWS Lambda function to do the need full.